# syntax error unexpected identifier javascript

Tags: javascript, php, joomla2.5

So, I have this small javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showModalCS() {
  if (window.location.href == "http://domainname.com/check/") {
      document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://domainname.com/style.min.css" />');
      document.writeln('<div id="popup"><span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span><img src="http://domainname.com/image.png" alt="" /></div>');
      document.writeln('<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js" /><script src="http://domainname.com/script.min.js" />');
      $("#popup").bPopup();
  } else {
      //
  }
}

showModalCS();

</script>
```

It works fine when I put it inside an html file and upload it using cpanel file manager.

But, when I use joomla's template manager to add this script to the bottom of the `index.php` it doesn't work. Instead I get an Unexpected Identifier error in chrome's dev tools...

Any ideas on **how to fix this?**

Comment: <script/> should be </script> last line

Comment: It's a bad way to add js script dynamical. use appendchild.

Comment: You are mixing jquery into your code, do you load jquery in joomla?

Comment: yeap, it's definitely loaded. chrome dev tools verifies that.

Answer (score 2):

change you last script tag to

```
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Script tag can never be self closing try this instead

```
  document.writeln('
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js">
</script><script src="http://domainname.com/script.min.js"></script>');
```

Comment: already tried that... the problem is that the script is not working  when I put it in the index.php using joomla's template editor... when I use an editor like notepad++ and re-upload the php file the script works okay with no error...